# DIsplaying HTML element if model count is empty - ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which displays one of two elements based on the Model.Count property. The code is as follows:

```
@if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
    <div class="well well-lg"><h3>Everybody is in! There are no absences today :)</h3></div>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="absencesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Date Out
                </th>
                <th>
                    Return Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Absence Type
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.FullName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.DateFrom.Value.ToLongDateString()
                        <span class="label label-default">@item.AbsencePeriodFrom.PeriodText</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.DateTo.Value.ToLongDateString()
                        <span class="label label-default">@item.AbsencePeriodTo.PeriodText</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.AbsenceType.AbsenceTypeText
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>    
    </table>
```

In my application I use jQuery to get data based on the selection of a date from a calendar control. My JavaScript code then appends rows to the absencesTable element. If there are no absences for the current day the table element will never be in the DOM. If I choose a date where there are records I modify the rows in the table. I realise why it's not working as it's simply because the table doesn't exist and so my ajax code is ignored. Here is my jQuery ajax call:

```
  $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function (data) {

            if (data != null && data.length != 0) {
                var $target = $("#absencesTable");

                $("#absencesTable tbody > tr").remove();

                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    var fromDate = new Date(element.DateFrom);
                    var toDate = new Date(element.DateTo);

                    var detailsStr = "<tr><td>" + element.FullName + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + moment(fromDate).format("DD MMMM YYYY") + " <span class=\"label label-default\">"
                        + element.AbsencePeriodFrom.PeriodText + "</span></td>"
                        + "<td>" + moment(toDate).format("DD MMMM YYYY") + " <span class=\"label label-default\">"
                        + element.AbsencePeriodTo.PeriodText + "</span></td>"
                        + "<td>" + element.AbsenceType.AbsenceTypeText + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>";

                    $("#absencesTable > tbody").append(detailsStr);
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#absencesTable tbody > tr").remove();

                var detailsStr = "<tr><td colspan=\"4\">No absences on that day</td></tr>";

                $("#absencesTable > tbody").append(detailsStr);
            }


        });
```

My question is how do I change my code so that my view remains the same - the table is only created if there is data otherwise display the "no records" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right you have initial data being loaded by the action (the if Model.Count part of your code), then you also have data loaded dynamically by AJAX.

What I'd probably do is have your well always in the DOM, in the view's definition check for Model.Count, if it's greater than 0 then set the style of your well to display=none; then do the opposite for your table.

In your javascript code call something like this

```
if (data != null && data.length != 0) {
    $(".well").hide();
    $("#absencesTable").show();
}
else {
    $(".well").show();
    $("#absencesTable").hide();
}
```

Of course you could give your well an ID and reference it that way also.

Comment: Yes that is correct. However there are scenarios where there is no data (which is how I found my bug) So the table is never rendered, only the well is. 

I like the suggestion but are you suggesting I render the table regardless of whether there is data? So both the well and table are rendered but in jQuery just show/hide as applicable?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm suggesting. You can start out with either the well or table hidden using `style="display:none;"`